# Sticky header is not always showing

Tags: css

I have converted the header on [this website](http://test.sscs.com/), so it always shows on top of page using `position:fixed`.

The problem is that when you scroll down towards the middle of the page, the header goes behind some other elements. I've tried fixing this issue with giving my header stronger z-index values but no luck yet. Looks like the elements that are more powerful have a `relative` positioning.

Can you think of a solution or a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should read** [**What No One Told You About Z-Index**](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

To fix your problem, be sure that there is no parent of your header with `position` different than `static` which has a `z-index` lower than one of its siblings (or its siblings descendants).

In your case, try adding `z-index:999` to `.bg_head`. It seems it works for now, but you should be aware of stacking contexts and stacking order.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I just noticed that ".tp-bullets" z-index is too high, try set a 700 or something hahaha.